# How to disable individual authentication in MVC Application

Tags: windows, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am editing a template with authentication enabled in MVC with OWIN. I want to disable the authentication in the template and use an oracle db in the server to login the users. I searched on how to disable the authentication but found no result. I don't have option for registration. The user should be logged in if the user name and password is in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some confusion.As far I can understand from your question you want to remove authentication because you want to use oracle authentication. But, You can keep your authentication module and use oracle db no problem. If you are using Microsoft Identity check [here](https://github.com/timmkrause/AspNet.Identity.OracleProvider) and [here](https://github.com/arichika/AspNet.Identity.Oracle). Things might have changed a bit.

You have to implement your for Oracle:

```
User (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser),
Role (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRole)
UserStore (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore)
UserManager (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager)
RolesStore (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore)
RoleManager (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i have been searching.